# Errores al crear las tablas

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

EStoy creado una base de datos en PHPmyadmin y me da estos errores. Podeis decirme que pasa? me da 7 8 veces el mismo solo cambia el numero de table estructure

Hay 2 tablas una PAis con id de contitennte que es in int autoincremnental un nombre varchar 30 y nº de habitantes que es un int de 11 y un tabla continente que es tiene una id y un nombre, LA id es la clave principal y ajena en la tabla pais y en la tabla pais la principal es el nombre –

```
Warning in .\libraries\classes\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController.php#1342
 Illegal string offset 'Index_length'

Backtrace

.\libraries\classes\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController.php#1278: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController->getTableStats()
.\libraries\classes\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController.php#377: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController->displayStructure(
array,
array,
array,
,
array,
array,
)
.\tbl_structure.php#57: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController->indexAction()
```

Comment: Pasanos la query con la que quieres crear la tabla,  o una imagen de la estructura de la tabla

Comment: hay 2 tablas una PAis con id de contitennte que es in int  autoincremnental un nombre varchar 30 y nº de habitantes que es un int de 11 
y un tabla continente que es tiene una id y un nombre, LA id es la clave principal y ajena en la tabla pais y en la tabla pais la principal es el nombre

Comment: Jeje, pon el sql ( CREATE TABLE ....) , así podemos ver si es el código para crear la tabla lo que está mal o es otra cosa